# Does Chromium browser get any updates if installed from repository?

Tags: updates, google-chrome, security, chromium, browser

As I understand it's not going to be updated entirely, but how about security patches ? I have thoughts that using Chromium is better for privacy (if compare to Chrome), but it is drawback in security.

Comment: All official ubuntu packages from official repositories are updated. Chromium is in there. so it too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chromium is in the official Ubuntu software repositories and is updated like everything else in the OS. See [Chromium's Launchpad page](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser).

That means, that all relevant security fixes are available as package upgrades through Canonical's `security` repository – either in form of a completely new version of the software (like for Chromium) or a so called "backport" of the security fix to the version currently released by Canonical (like for core system libraries or the Linux kernel).